# How to create node with image in drupal 7 using REST server PHP CURL?

Tags: php, drupal, curl

I am trying to create a node with image using **drupal 7 REST server**, I have configured REST server properly, I am able to create node with simple text as its body, I want to able to post image also i.e. I should be able to display image in newly created node or at least should be able to attach image to node body?
 so far I am doing it like this, how can I attach/display image in node's body? I am doing this via an external PHP script

```
 $node_data = array(
  'title' => "this is test node",
  'type' => 'blog',
  'body[und][0][value]' => 'this is test node description'
);

$node_data = http_build_query($node_data);
$cookie_session = $logged_user->session_name . '=' . $logged_user->sessid;

// cURL
$curl = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json')); // Accept JSON response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Do a regular HTTP POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $node_data); // Set POST data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);  // Ask to not return Header
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$cookie_session"); // use the previously saved session
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I am able to post images to newly created drupal node. I managed to do it by specifying the node body as "full_html". added following parameter in node_data array

```
'body[und][0][format]' =>'full_html'
```

with this I can post content as html content, hence image can be embedded in it.

BTW there are three options are available:

```
filtered_html
full_html
plain_text
```